# Produce equal length of rows for each value in another column (using Python or SQL)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

My original data in the table is organised as below format:

```
    routes    demand days
Paris-New York    1
Paris-New York    3
Paris-New York    5
London-Berlin     2
London-Berlin     3
London-Berlin     4
London-Berlin     5
Tokyo-Shanghai    2
Tokyo-Shanghai    4
```

The desired format I want in the new table:

```
     routes   calendar days  demand-days
Paris-New York    1              1
Paris-New York    2              
Paris-New York    3              3
Paris-New York    4
Paris-New York    5              5
London-Berlin     1
London-Berlin     2              2
London-Berlin     3              3
London-Berlin     4              4
London-Berlin     5              5
Tokyo-Shanghai    1
Tokyo-Shanghai    2              2
Tokyo-Shanghai    3
Tokyo-Shanghai    4              4
Tokyo-Shanghai    5
```

I just want to generate a new column (e.g. "calendar days") with the equal number of rows for every unique routes in column "routes". Is there a simply way to do it with either Python or SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pandas** solution working if for each `routes` are unique `demand days`:

```
df = df.set_index(['routes']).set_index('demand days', drop=False, append=True)
df = (df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels,names=('routes','calendar days')))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
            routes  calendar days  demand days
0    London-Berlin              1          NaN
1    London-Berlin              2          2.0
2    London-Berlin              3          3.0
3    London-Berlin              4          4.0
4    London-Berlin              5          5.0
5   Paris-New York              1          1.0
6   Paris-New York              2          NaN
7   Paris-New York              3          3.0
8   Paris-New York              4          NaN
9   Paris-New York              5          5.0
10  Tokyo-Shanghai              1          NaN
11  Tokyo-Shanghai              2          2.0
12  Tokyo-Shanghai              3          NaN
13  Tokyo-Shanghai              4          4.0
14  Tokyo-Shanghai              5          NaN
```

EDIT:

Dynamic solution for `reindex` by `range`:

```
df = df.set_index(['routes']).set_index('demand days', drop=False, append=True)
#get values of routes
a = df.index.levels[0]
#get minimal and maximal days
b = range(min(df.index.levels[1]), max(df.index.levels[1]) + 1)
#create MulitIndex
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b],names=('routes','calendar days'))
#reinex
df = df.reindex(mux).reset_index()
```

Comment: I actually want the 'calendar days' as consecutive accumulation from the  min (e.g. min demand days is 45) to the max (e.g. max demand day is 365). i.e. step size = 1

Comment: @Jack - Not sure if understand, can you change answer with expected output?

Comment: I want the 'calendar days' to be consecutive like 1-365 for all routes. The min demand day in my actual data is 41 and max demand day is 151. So I need the 'calendar days' as 41-151 rows for every routes so could do the mapping between 'calendar days' and 'demand days' like your example.

Answer (score 1):

First do a cross-product on routes and demand_days to get all possible combination (all demand days for all routes). Rename "demand_days" to "calendar days". Let's call the result A.

Then, (outer) merge A with your initial dataset on demand_days = calendar_days.

Answer (score 0):

My solution provides creation of temporary table along with your table.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`routes` varchar(14), `demand_days` int)
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`routes`, `demand_days`)
VALUES
    ('Paris-New York', 1),
    ('Paris-New York', 3),
    ('Paris-New York', 5),
    ('London-Berlin', 2),
    ('London-Berlin', 3),
    ('London-Berlin', 4),
    ('London-Berlin', 5),
    ('Tokyo-Shanghai', 2),
    ('Tokyo-Shanghai', 4)
;

create  table t1 (val int);
insert into t1 (val) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Main query-

```
select distinct routes,val,(select demand_days from mytable where routes=m1.routes and demand_days=t1.val )
from mytable m1 right join t1 
on m1.demand_days=t1.val
union
select distinct routes,val ,(select demand_days from mytable where routes=m1.routes and demand_days=t1.val )
from mytable m1 right join t1 
on m1.demand_days<>t1.val
order by 1,2
```

What I have done is using the new table joined with your table to get common and uncommon demand_days.